# The usage of word "prior" in logistic regression with intercept only

Tags: logistic, bayesian, terminology

Suppose I am fitting a logistic regression with intercept only, which is equivalent tho using the count to estimate the outcome probability and make prediction.

Can I say following?

> We are using prior only to make the prediction.

I think some persons from CV corrected me, that the word `prior` has close relationship with Bayesian statistics, and the statement is not correct.

If it is not accurate, what should I say if we only use the counts to estimate the outcome probability?

Comment: Try: We are using "counts" only to make the prediction"

Comment: Unless you're doing Bayesian Logistic regression, don't use the word prior.

Comment: If I read that, it would sound like a tautology. Of course in any Bayesian estimation a prior is used to make the posterior which is the prediction! Just don't use the word prior if it's not Bayesian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say it's fine.

Logistic regression estimates $P(Y = 1\vert X = x)$.

$$
P(Y = 1\vert X = x) 
=
\dfrac{
P(X = x\vert Y = 1)P(Y = 1)
}{
P(X = x)
}
$$

$P(Y = 1)$ is the prior probability that $Y = 1$.

If we only use an intercept in our model, no matter what features we have, then the probability predicted by the logistic regression model is the proportion of $Y$-values with $Y = 1$. This is $P(Y = 1)$, so the prior probability that $Y = 1$.

Answer (score -1):

Answered in comments by Jon:

> Try: We are using "counts" only to make the prediction". Unless you're
> doing Bayesian Logistic regression, don't use the word prior.