# Unbalanced data on fire for a binary classifier

Tags: classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I have a lot of training data from which I want to build a binary classifier, but the classes are highly unbalanced, 97% in one class, 3% in the other (even though, in absolute terms, I still have a lot of data, thousands of observations) in each class.

I know there are a lot of fancy algorithms to deal with unbalanced classes, but for lack of time I just want to know in my scenario: Is it safe to throw away a lot of the labelled data from the larger class, so that I have roughly the same amount of labels of both types and then split this dataset into a training(+crossvalidation) and test dataset?

Comment: It's possible, but "safe" ? You're throwing away a decent amount of information that might help in solving the classification problem. A properly [calibrated](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) model might help you without needing to discard data.

Comment: @Rickyfox That sounds like a good idea! If you could elaborate that a bit more and let me know how I could do that in my specific problem, I could accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Class imbalance is almost certainly not a problem for proper statistical methods.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) Therefore, throwing away precious data just to fix a non-problem seems like the worst approach one can take. Additionally, by throwing away many instances of the majority category, you alter the [prior probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/583115/247274) of membership in that category, which will affect the posterior (predicted) probability through Bayes' theorem. [It is possible to fix this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/558950/247274), but why would you throw away precious data to solve a non-problem just to have to fix a real problem later that only exists because you tried to solve a non-problem?

From King and Zeng (2001), [it can make sense to downsample at the stage of collecting data.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/613921/247274) If you have too large of a data set to run it on your hardware, it might make sense to apply ideas like those of King and Zeng (2001), giving your hardware a break without discarding especially precious observations from the minority category (and then calibrating the predictions to account for this). However, getting rid of precious data just to solve a non-problem seems like a poor approach.

**REFERENCE**

King, Gary, and Langche Zeng. "Logistic regression in rare events data." Political analysis 9.2 (2001): 137-163.